# How can I find the id of a custom emoji the user sent and add it to the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making an `addemoji` command (for custom emojis), and I'm having trouble trying to define/find the id to the emoji that the user sends and then adding it to the server. I wrote some code myself and so far I've had no luck.

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "addemoji",
    description: "ping pong",
    execute(message, args) {
        const Discord = require("discord.js");
        const bot = new Discord.Client();
        const nothing = "<:nothing:823792064658407424>";
        const PREFIX = "ly?";

        if (message.content.startsWith(PREFIX + "addemoji")) {
            if (message.guild.me.permissions.has("MANAGE_EMOJIS")) {
                let emojiid = message.content.has.emojis(fetch.id);

                Guild.emojis.create(emojiid);
            }

            message.channel.send(`Emoji Added!`);
        } else {
            message.channel.send("This emoji already exists.");
        }
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom emojis are of the form `<:NAME:ID>` (non-animated) or `<a:NAME:ID>` (animated).

To get the details of the first emoji in the message, you could use this:

```js
const match = /<(a?):(.+):(\d+)>/u.exec(message.content);
if (!match) return message.reply('Please include a custom emoji in your message!')
// animated will be 'a' if it is animated or '' if it isn't
const [, animated, name, id] = match
```

Then, to get the URL of the image of the emoji, you use the format `https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/<emoji id>.<png or gif>`:

```js
const url = `https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/${id}.${animated ? 'gif' : 'png'}`
```

For more information on this, see the [Discord developer docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference).

Finally, you can add the emoji:

```js
message.guild.emojis.create(url, name)
```

Comment: This works and doesn't work at the same time, I ran it, and now it says "image: Invalid image data" and "name: This field is required". I tried to code it in different ways so I wouldn't have to ask for help, but I'm just stuck now. I believe it's because match is pulling the name, id and if it's an animated, I added `message.reply(`<${id}> added!`)` and the bot says "<:weSmart:,,weSmart,421097576738193409>" and obviously that's not a valid url, but knowing that, I still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @neon Sorry about that. I've fixed my code.